# Building WinUI 3 Desktop Application using LLVM/Clang

Tags: msbuild, clang, winui-3, cppwinrt

When I create a WinUI project in Visual Studio, below is how the project structure looks like:
[image: WinUI App Project structure]

This project by default gets built using MSBuild.

However, I would like to build this project using LLVM Clang-Cl. Stating for ample clarity, I would also be wanting to use the Generator as 'Ninja'.

Is this possible to achieve?

As a bunch of headers get generated when this project is built, I tried using running cppwinrt.exe manually on this project to generate the relevant headers. While few headers got generated but still a bunch were missing. Also, could not understand how the .g.h/.g.cpp files can get generated without MSBuild.

I have also tried this link - https://github.com/fredemmott/cmake-cpp-winrt-winui3. However, the same doesnt work with LLVM/Clang and Ninja.

Any pointers/suggestions will help.

Comment: Nothing is really impossible in our development business, isn't it? The question is really the (sometimes huge) amount of work vs the gain. Officially, LLVM/Clang is not supported by C++/WinRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/faq#can-i-use-llvm-clang-to-compile-with-c---winrt- states "We don't support the LLVM and Clang toolchain for C++/WinRT", but its probably "possible". Good luck with that.

Comment: True That. Thanks for sharing this link. Had stumbled upon this yesterday. While I understand the official statement, I am tryin out building it using LLVM/Clang assuming all the generated files are available. However, I am not sure what all happens under the hood in MSBuild, that leads to all the generated files from the winmd, idl, xaml files etc.

Comment: You can use the [MSBuild Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) to gather insights into the build process.